# Implementing mysqli procedural with a class

Tags: php, mysqli

so recently I've been trying to use more procedural mysqli for practise, and have been looking at http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/mysqli-procedural-functions/, and also w3schools as reference, but i'm still having trouble so I thought I'd ask.

I have this database.php file where I have alot of stuff but the important stuff is

```
class Database{
    public $host = DB_HOST;
    public $username = DB_USER;
    public $password = DB_PASS;
    public $db_name = DB_NAME;

    public $link; 
    public $error;

   public function __construct(){

       $this -> connect();
   }

    private function connect(){

       $link = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->username,$this->password,$this->db_name);
        if(!$link){
            echo "Failed".mysqli_error($link);
        }
    }



    // create select method

    public function select($query){
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$query) or die("didnt work".mysqli_error($link));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now the way it currently works fine in my index.php file is simply by doing something like

```
$db = new Database();

//CREATe query
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$posts = $db->select($query);
```

Is there any way to implement `$posts = $db->select($query)` with procedural functions? Before I have done stuff like `mysqli_query($link,$query)`, but `link` is public here and inside a class so I can't do that, plus I want to access the function `select` . Thanks!

Comment: @Saty, gives "Using $this when not in object context error"

Comment: Why there is a class if you want a function?

Comment: I just thought putting a class and some functions inside would be a better way to organize my code. This is the first time im organizing everything in a class. Before it was kind of just doing things like selecting,inserting, on the fly, but this seems neater

Comment: I still don't understand neither your intention nor problem. If you want to use a class, then stick to using a class. If you want to use a function, then get rid of a class and go for a function.

Comment: I'm asking whether $posts = $db->select($query); can be transformed into something of the form $posts = mysqli_query(something here)

Comment: why not to create a function select() right from the beginning? Why there is a class?

Comment: I've seen a tutorial do a similar layout to this ( all I did was just change some functions to my own needs)

Comment: Then you choose a wrong tutorial for your needs

Comment: I see, however I am wondering is this possible? Regardless of whether this is a bad practice?

Comment: Why not to create a function already, without any useless classes from a wrong tutorial?

Comment: What do you mean create a function? I have about 6 public functions noww which serve roles of deleting posts, inserting posts etc etc. Couldnt that warrant the need to use a class. I only showed up to the select function here, since I thought that was where the error was from

Comment: what error you are talking about?

Comment: My error relies on the fact that i'm not sure how to change the currently working $posts = $db->select($query);, into $posts = mysqli_query($link,$query). The problem is that I can't acess the variable link so I'm wondering how can I access this inside db. doing mysqli_query($this -> $link, $query) does not work either as someone suggested before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$link` is not defined in your function `select`.

Modify your `connect` function:

```
private function connect() {
    $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);
    if(!$this->link) {
        echo "Failed: " . mysqli_error($this->link);
    }
}
```

Now $this->link may be used in your `select` function:

```
public function select($query){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query) or die("didn't work: "  .mysqli_error($this->link));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        return $result;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I suggest you read the [PHP OOP documenentation](http://php.net/oop) (at least the first chapters) to get a better understanding.

Comment: Hmm, I actually was toying around with this earlier and did the same, however I get the error "Using $this when not in object context in", when I do "$posts = mysqli_query($this->link,$query);"

Comment: `$this` may only be used within a class. Why are you calling mysqli_query instead of your `select` function?

Comment: Oh. So should I just be doing $posts = (call function here)?

Comment: `$posts = $db->select(your query here);` You don't have to worry about the link value, it is stored in `$db` and used automatically when you call `select` function.

Comment: Is that because I said public $link in the beginning? I think I need to study classes and OOP in php again, its been a while..

Comment: I added a link to documentation. `public $link` says your class contains a member variable with that name. This member variable is referenced within the class using `$this->link`.

Comment: Great, I'll do some reading. By our same logic our $error is also stored in $db as well then?

Comment: Currently, `$this->error` exists within the class, but is never initialized nor used anywhere.

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate for me to do some reading and tutorial watching for a day or two then come back to you and ask, if you dont mind